# find the string and print out the line before and after- unix scripting

Tags: unix, printing, scripting

right now i have this code

```
 FNR==NR  { id[$0]; next } 
 $0 in id { f=1 }         
 f                          
 NF==0    { f=0 }
```

and i want to print out the line before the string found as well.

How would i modify this code to do so??

Comment: Presumably, what you've got is an `awk` script.  Maybe you have GNU `grep`, in which case you can use `grep -B 1 -A 1 pattern file1 ...` to get the lines before and after each match.  In `awk`, you have to keep the previous line around so that when you find a match, you can print the previous line.  But you have to worry about finding the pattern on two consecutive lines, or on one line and the next but one (so you need to print 5 lines; line1, match1, line3, match2, line5).

Comment: how would i be able to keep the previous line?? is there a way i could combine both grep scripts and awk in one script?

Comment: If you've got GNU `grep` there's not really any need to use `awk` too.  If you've not got GNU `grep`, then you need to think about which lines need printing.  I've got a Perl script that handles the job; it isn't `awk` and I'm not about to rewrite it in `awk`, though it is probably not very hard to do (the option handling would probably be hardest, actually, but that could be done in shell script that sets up the awk correctly).

Comment: Actually i don't mind which language i use... i used awk because thats what i know... if i use grep, i'm not sure how to complete my other tasks of grabbing a line from one file and searching for it in another. .. I'm a big noob at scripting in the first place.

Comment: That sounds like a task for `grep -F -f file1 -A 1 -B 1 file2`.  The `grep -F` (also known as `fgrep`) looks for fixed words (not patterns); the `-f` means read the words from the file; the `-A 1` and `-B 1` look for one line after and one line before; and the search is done in `file2`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the Perl script I referred to, `sgrep`.  The change this year was to use `#!/usr/bin/env perl` instead of `#!/path/to/perl/v5.16.2/bin/perl` line.  Otherwise, it was written in September 2007.  I expect there is room for improvement.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#
# @(#)$Id: sgrep.pl,v 1.7 2013/01/28 02:07:18 jleffler Exp $
#
# Perl-based SGREP (special grep) command
# 
# Print lines around the line that matches (by default, 3 before and 3 after).
# By default, include file names if more than one file to search.
#
# Options:
# -b n1     Print n1 lines before match
# -f n2     Print n2 lines following match
# -n        Print line numbers
# -h        Do not print file names
# -H        Do     print file names

use warnings;
use strict;
use constant debug => 0;
use Getopt::Std;
my(%opts);

sub usage
{
    print STDERR "Usage: $0 [-hnH] [-b n1] [-f n2] pattern [file ...]\n";
    exit 1;
}

usage unless getopts('hnf:b:H', \%opts);
usage unless @ARGV >= 1;

if ($opts{h} && $opts{H})
{
    print STDERR "$0: mutually exclusive options -h and -H specified\n";
    exit 1;
}

my $op = shift;

print "# regex = $op\n" if debug;

# print file names if -h omitted and more than one argument
$opts{F} = (defined $opts{H} || (!defined $opts{h} and scalar @ARGV > 1)) ? 1 : 0;
$opts{n} = 0 unless defined $opts{n};

my $before = (defined $opts{b}) ? $opts{b} + 0 : 3;
my $after  = (defined $opts{f}) ? $opts{f} + 0 : 3;

print "# before = $before; after = $after\n" if debug;

my @lines = (); # Accumulated lines
my $tail  = 0;  # Line number of last line in list
my $tbp_1 = 0;  # First line to be printed
my $tbp_2 = 0;  # Last line to be printed

# Print lines from @lines in the range $tbp_1 .. $tbp_2,
# leaving $leave lines in the array for future use.
sub print_leaving
{
    my ($leave) = @_;
    while (scalar(@lines) > $leave)
    {
        my $line = shift @lines;
        my $curr = $tail - scalar(@lines);
        if ($tbp_1 <= $curr && $curr <= $tbp_2)
        {
            print "$ARGV:" if $opts{F};
            print "$curr:" if $opts{n};
            print $line;
        }
    }
}

# General logic:
# Accumulate each line at end of @lines.
# ** If current line matches, record range that needs printing
# ** When the line array contains enough lines, pop line off front and,
#    if it needs printing, print it.
# At end of file, empty line array, printing requisite accumulated lines.

while (<>)
{
    # Add this line to the accumulated lines
    push @lines, $_;
    $tail = $.;

    printf "# array: N = %d, last = $tail: %s", scalar(@lines), $_ if debug > 1;

    if (m/$op/o)
    {
        # This line matches - set range to be printed
        my $lo = $. - $before;
        $tbp_1 = $lo if ($lo > $tbp_2);
        $tbp_2 = $. + $after;
        print "# $. MATCH: print range $tbp_1 .. $tbp_2\n" if debug;
    }

    # Print out any accumulated lines that need printing
    # Leave $before lines in array.
    print_leaving($before);
}
continue
{
    if (eof)
    {
        # Print out any accumulated lines that need printing
        print_leaving(0);
        # Reset for next file
        close ARGV;
        $tbp_1 = 0;
        $tbp_2 = 0;
        $tail  = 0;
        @lines = ();
    }
}
```

It uses options `-b 1` for lines before match and `-f 1` for lines after match instead of `-A` and `-B`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have gnu grep, or a grep that supports `-C`, you can do:

```
grep -w -f file1 -C 1 input
```

The `-w` makes `grep` only match whole words, and is intended to mimic your `awk` script's
matching, but will not do quite the same thing (it's not clear to me exactly what matching you want to do)  You may prefer to omit the `-w`.

In awk, you can do something like:

```
FNR==NR  { id[$0]; next }
$0 in id { print prev; f=1 }         
f{ f += 1; print}                          
f == 3 { f=0 }
{ prev = $0 }
```